# In C++, how can I get a pointer for an object's "emit" method?

Tags: c++, pointers, signals, signals-slots

I'm currently working on a project of which I have two main objects.
Object A has a well-build signal-slot interface.
Object B has an instance of object A.
I wish to emit a signal to object A, changing object A the least possible- meaning I want to use object A's emit method to send a signal to itself.

I think a good way to do that is that object A will have a method that will give a pointer to it's emit method. object B will use that method and simply emit signals to object A.
The only problem is that I don't know how (and if that is possible), to actually extract an objects emit method, and a pointer to it.

Thank you very much!

Comment: using QT? which version?

Comment: Er, what? Can you please be a *lot* more specific? What does "emit a signal to itself" mean? Can't you just connect a signal to one of `A`'s slots and emit that signal? Also, what kind of signals & slots are you using: Qt; Boost; ...?

Comment: Yes, using QT version 4.7.3. Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: It's hard to answer without knowing the exact signal-slot implementation... If "emit" is a member function of an "Object" class, then you can get a pointer using &Object::emit and call it using ((objectA).(*ptr))()

Comment: @BarHarel You can edit your questions to add missing information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt signals are implemented as `protected` member functions. Emitting them is just calling the member function (notice that the pseudo-keyword `emit` is effectively removed by the preprocessor, because it expands to nothing) This means that you cannot emit a signal from outside a class.

You can connect one signal to another, however. Emitting the first one will cause the second one to be emitted as well. So you can just add an appropriate signal to `B`:

```
class B : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

  B();

  A a;

signals:
  void emitASignal();
};

B::B()
{
  connect(this, SIGNAL(emitASignal()), &a, SIGNAL(theSignalYouWantToEmit()));
}
```

Then, doing `emit emitASignal();` will cause `theSignalYouWantToEmit()` to be emitted from `a`.

Answer (score 0):

In Qt "emit" is not a method, it is syntatic sugar which boils down to

```
#define emit
```

So you can't do this. If you want to emit a signal from the other object then connect the slot on A to B or B to A.